# setting an application controller variable to results returned from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to reset a variable in the application controller to a value returned from an AJAX call.  The code shown below doesn't work because 'this' doesn't have the correct context. Server returns a value different than 15, but 2nd console.log still outputs 15.  I've also tried App.ApplicationController.set ('x', data) and controllers.application.set ('x', data), and a few other possibilities.  None worked.  What's the correct way of doing this?

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({

x: 15,

init: function() {
console.log(this.get('x'));
$.getJSON ("strats/limits.json")
    .done (function (data){this.set('x', data);});
    console.log(this.get('x')}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yours is just a `JavaScript` problem...  Try this:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({

    x: 15,

    init: function() {
        var self= this;
        console.log(self.get('x'));
        $.getJSON ("strats/limits.json")
            .done (function (data){self.set('x', data);});
        console.log(self.get('x');
    }
});
```

Always be careful using "this" and remember nested functions may have a different value!

Comment: Also, the 2nd console.log will always print the same value as the first.  `getJSON()` does not block, it returns immediately and asynchronously calls the `done` function later.