# Ember access model inside a controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How can a model be accessed from within a controller ? Currently using the below code returns a "undefined is not a function" (go figure JS fail...).

**models/plan.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name:       DS.attr('string'),
    period:     DS.attr('number'),
    price:      DS.attr('number'),
});
```

**routes/checkout.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('plan', params.plan_id);
    }
});
```

**controllers/checkout.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    submitPayment: function(error, result)
    {
          var plan = this.get('model');
    }
}
```

**router.js**

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('checkout', {path: '/checkout/:plan_id'});
});
```

Comment: maybe 'this' is not the controller in 'submitPayment'. Is submitPayment an action? If so you should put it inside an actions object. Or checkout the usuals, is model being fetched in the model hook?

Comment: submitPayment is just a function being called from within an action. Yes, the model is being stored, no problems there.

Comment: Instead of extending 'Ember.Controller', try 'Ember.ObjectController'.

Comment: No difference. Altough if I user this.get('model') inside the action instead of the function from above, I get an object. It has only the id set however, instead of all the fields. Why is that ? Also, if I use this.get('model.price') I get the actual price. So how can I get the entire model inside a single variable ?

Comment: Im not that familiar with ember data. You might need to call this.get('model').toJSON()

Comment: If you're not familiar, why are you commenting? No, you do **not** need to  call `toJSON` on the model.

Comment: Nothing is obviously wrong here. What line is the error message occurring on?

Comment: I've figured it out eventually. plan = this.get('model') works for the action. It returns the model, and the properties can be accessed with plan.get('price'). Not ideal, but it gets the job done. Why it didn't work is because it was inside a function that was called as a callback from inside the action. So probably the scope of "this" wasn't carried out to the callback function as well. I moved the callback function as an inner function inside the action, then "this" scope worked.

Comment: Any idea though as to why you can't access a controller variable from a JS callback (ex. AJAX success callback) ? If I want to use this.set('variable', value); inside the AJAX success callback, I get the undefined is not a function error. Nvm, found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985916/setting-an-application-controller-variable-to-results-returned-from-ajax-call

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've figured it out eventually. `plan = this.get('model')` works for the action. It returns the model, and the properties can be accessed with `plan.get('price')`. Not ideal, but it gets the job done. Why it didn't work is because it was inside a function that was called as a callback from inside the action. So probably the scope of "this" wasn't carried out to the callback function as well. I moved the callback function as an inner function inside the action, then "this" scope worked.

As for the scope problem, here's the solution [setting an application controller variable to results returned from AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985916/setting-an-application-controller-variable-to-results-returned-from-ajax-call)

Comment: I'm not able to use this.get() inside a controller. 

Ex: export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  model: this.get('model'),
  message: this.model.message, .... ..

Comment: Figured it out. It works like this in a controller: 
message: Ember.computed.alias('model.message'),...